# Правильно ли написано: "Однозначного мнения, поддерживаемого большинством..."?

Tags: стилистика

"Однозначного мнения, поддерживаемого большинством исследователей, не существует" — корректна ли фраза?

Answer (score 2):

*"Однозначное мнение"* сказано не очень удачно, так как по значениям слова не очень сопоставимы, тем более нелепы в контексте.  *"Единое мнение"* или *"единая точка зрения"*  было бы куда лучше.